# AJAX form is submitting even if jQuery Validations are failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form where we implemented jQuery validation

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="mobile" data-validation="required number length" data-validation-length="10">
```

When we are submitting form through Ajax, even if validation are failing, browser submits the form. Here is our Ajax Submit Code

```
$('#add-admin-form').on('submit', function(event){
 
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      url:"/submit-create-Admin-User",
      method:"POST",
      data:new FormData(this),
      dataType:'JSON',
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success:function(data)
      {
          if(data.status == 1 ) {
              $("#create_admin_modal").modal('hide');
              swal("Done", "Admin user added successfully.", "success");
              location.reload();
          } else if(data.status == -1 ) {
              swal("Ooops", data.message, "failure");
          } else {
              swal("Ooops", "Something went wrong. Please try again.", "failure");
          }
      },
      failure: function() { swal("Ooops", "Something went wrong. Please try again.", "failure");}
  })
 });
```

To prevent form submission we added this code block but this is not working

```
var form = $(this);
if (!form.validate()) {
    return false;
}
```

Please guide how we can stop this behavior.

Comment: Where does this validation code run?

Comment: 1) You're showing an input field, not the entire form; please show all details. 2) The `data-*` attributes are no standard HTML validation, nor does a plain jQuery selector method `validate()` exist, so either you expect them to work magically (but they won't) or the question is missing some essential information about the validation library you're using.